# How to get the backing field for the property (AssociatedPropertyOrEvent is null)?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to use Roslyn to get the reference to the symbol (FieldSymbol) for  backing field of the property, but AssociatedPropertyOrEvent is null. 
Here is the unit test that fails.

```
[Test]
public void Get_BackingField_for_Property()
{

    var sourceCode = @" public class Player
                    {
                        private Person _MyPerson;

                        public virtual Person MyPerson
                        {
                            get { return _MyPerson; }
                        }

                        public virtual void Set(Person person)
                        {
                            _MyPerson = person;
                        }
                    }";


    var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);


    var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference(
                                     "mscorlib");


    var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                    .AddReferences(mscorlib)
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

    //var  semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

    var classSymbol =
        compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("Player");

    Assert.That(classSymbol,Is.Not.Null, "class");

    var propertySymbol = classSymbol.GetMembers().Where(x => x.Kind == SymbolKind.Property);

    Assert.That(propertySymbol, Is.Not.Null, "property");

    var backingField = classSymbol.GetMembers().Where(x=>x.Kind== SymbolKind.Field).Cast<FieldSymbol>().First();

    Assert.That(backingField.AssociatedPropertyOrEvent, Is.Not.Null,"backing field");
```

Update: For anybody trying to do the same INotifyPropertyChaged sample has code that gets backing field of the property. I modified it to fit my needs. Here is the code

```
internal static IFieldSymbol GetBackingField(this IPropertySymbol property, ISemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    var propertyDelcarationSyntax = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)property.DeclaringSyntaxNodes.First();

    var getter = propertyDelcarationSyntax.AccessorList.Accessors.First(a => a.Kind == SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration);

    return GetBackingFieldFromGetter(getter, semanticModel);
}
private static IFieldSymbol GetBackingFieldFromGetter(AccessorDeclarationSyntax getter, ISemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    // The getter should have a body containing a single return of a backing field.

    if (getter.Body == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Missing a getter body for property " + semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(getter.Parent).Name);
    }

    var statements = getter.Body.Statements;
    if (statements.Count != 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("Getter body has more then one statement for property " + semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(getter.Parent).Name);
    }

    var returnStatement = statements.Single() as ReturnStatementSyntax;
    if (returnStatement == null || returnStatement.Expression == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Getter body is missing a return statement for property " + semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(getter.Parent).Name);
    }

    return semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(returnStatement.Expression).Symbol as IFieldSymbol;
}
```

Comment: Private members in general aren't testable.  I'm curious why test the property and the backing field?  Seems to be breaking encapsulation to do such a thing.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Did you bother to look at the code?

Comment: Roslyn is a code gen API.  `Assert.That` is part of NUnit.  The assertion is what fails.  So I fail to see how Roslyn has any impact on private member accessibility.  I still see this as a unit test which can't access a private member which is perfectly normal.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey : Private member of what? I am asking roslyn to give me symbol for the field, which it does. Then I ask it, to tell me the property it is associated with, and that returns null. To prove my point, change the property to private and it will not fail on assert for property. I think you are, to say the least, misreading the code.

Comment: Are we sure that AssociatedPropertyOrEvent should have a value? e.g. what would happen if you had  `public virtual Person MyPerson                        { get { return _MyPerson; }`  and `public virtual Person MyPerson2                        { get { return _MyPerson; }` what would the value of AssociatedPropertyOrEvent be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `AssociatedPropertyOrEvent` says:

> If this field serves as a backing variable for an automatically generated property or a field-like event, returns that property/event. Otherwise returns null.

Since your field has no relation to any autoproperties, `AssociatedPropertyOrEvent` correctly returns `null`.

In general, what you're asking is impossible, because there could be many properties that access the same field.

Answer (score 0):

You can only go the other way with the current API.  Use `GetMembers` to get all of them, and then find the field whose `AssociatedPropertyOrEvent` is the property you want.